# How do I get chunky looking snow in a snowglobe?

Tags: miniatures

I've been searching all over for something to use as snow in a snowglobe.  Most places suggest glitter, but the photos of the finished projects look very unproffessional.

I did find someone on etsy selling ["genuine snow globe snow"](https://www.etsy.com/listing/115385922/genuine-snow-globe-snow-for-diy-snow), and it does look correct.  But it is also extremely expensive for what seems like little chunks of plastic.

**How can I get affordable and chunky looking snow for a snow globe?**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Nothing like asking to make the perfect link finally appear: https://coolsnowglobes.com/pages/history-of-snow-globes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there are several different options available in different shops and at quite different price points. However, there might be some crafty alternatives you could try.

**Egg shells**: break the shells of 1 - 2 white eggs into pieces the size you want. Make sure to either use the shells of boiled eggs or boil the empty shells before crushing them. Rinse out the fine dust before filling the pieces into the snow globe.

**Bleached sponge**: rip the sponge into tiny pieces. This may work with natural and artificial sponges and probably even with loofas or similar materials, although loofa probably creates a very different impression due to the stringy fibers. Natural sponges usually sink in water, but many artificial ones probably float.

**Polymer clay**: Honestly I'm not sure if polymer clay particles float on water or sink to the bottom. But it's water resistant after baking and often used for the actual figures in snow globes. If it does float on water, maybe try if it sinks into baby oil instead (see below).

**Aluminum foil**: cut it into small pieces for an alternative to glitter. You can roll the pieces between your hands to make chunky glitter flakes.

**Additives to the water**: There are several different substances you can add to the water to make the snow particles sink slower. Those include:

- 2 table spoons (or more) of glycerin per cup of water
- 2 table spoons (or more) of clear glue (like Elmers) per cup of water
- Fill the globe with baby oil instead of water

You can see a comparison of these materials [here on YouTube](https://youtu.be/cjyn_3wFXDc)

The baby oil has a much higher viscosity than water, so it may open up opportunities for other chunky snow materials like white sand, crushed glass or crushed sea shells that would sink too quickly in plain water.